# Responsive menus not working in IE

Tags: internet-explorer, mobile, menu, responsive-design, hamburger-menu

Our responsive menus are not working in IE, rather they work at full width, but then disappear and show only white space at more narrow window width (around 800px wide). Unfortunately around 20% of our users view the site IE and Windows phones so we have to be concerned with this. Any ideas?

http://www.sosc.org/letr

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You site is being forced into using the IE9 as your web server is passing a
X-UA-Compatible header and setting it to IE=9. If you open up your F12 developer tools and change the rendering mode to IE11 you will notice that the site works the same as in Chrome.

The way you fix this is to stop your site passing down that header.

IE9 is unable to display your menu since you are using CSS features that it doesn't support.

Note: It appears adding

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
```

overrides the setting in the headers and so by adding this meta tag you can resolve this issue.

Comment: Would the code <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"> work to fix it? We are using a CMS that puts a lot of stuff in there that we don't necessarily want.

Comment: Yes. This will work. I just tested this and adding that meta tag overrides what comes down in the headers. I tested your responsive menu, it works in IE10 and IE11.

Comment: Out of interest what CMS are you using, seems a strange thing for it to add. Are you sure you aren't adding it at an IIS level?

Comment: Its Blackbaud Net Community. It's possible it didn't put any code in, but it has happened before in the past so I just assumed that is what happened. I didn't design the website or write the original code either so I'm still trying to figure out why certain code was written and for what reason (they didn't notate it that well). The fix worked great. Thanks for the information!